# How to Factory Reset Toshiba Satellite a215-S7416?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-vista, toshiba-laptop

My question is almost exactly like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/568747/laptop-is-asking-for-password-which-i-never-set-even-when-without-hard-drive), except:

1) I know my BIOS password and I just want to factory reset
2) I have a Toshiba Satellite a215-s7416 (Vista)

When I get past the "Enter Password", I get options such as "USB", "HDD", "FDD", etc. but when I select HDD, it just goes to the login screen

Answer (score 0):

Normally just holding "0" when you boot should bring up the factory reset options for vista on a Toshiba.  If your talking resetting the bios though holding down F2 should bring up bios menu and you can reset from there. Or you can open up your laptop and remove the CMOS battery.